# Python function changing global variable?

Tags: python, scope

So I have a question that pertains to the scope of variables in functions in python, consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np


def function(data, mask):
    data *= mask


data = np.ones(5)
for x in range(2):
    print(data)
    mask = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    function(data, mask)
```

And the output is the following:

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

My question is why `data` changes after the first iteration? I always thought that the local variable of a function was... local, so any modification would remain confined within the scope of the function. Clearly I was wrong. Is this because `data` in the function is still referencing the same object as the `data` in the global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, mutable objects passed to a function will mutate in-place if requested. Specifically, you are telling `function` to mutate `data` in-place by using the operator `*=`. If, on the other hand, you don't want `data` to mutate, simply do

`data = data * mask`

which will simply assign the local (i.e. within the `function` scope) *tag* `data` to a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` in the `function` can be a different one than the global `data`, because it's passed as a parameter. The name is the same, so it shadows the global, but they are otherwise unrelated...

... *until* you call `function(data, mask)`, passing the global `data` in. The function modifies the local `data`, but because it refers to the same object as the global one, the change is visible outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make a copy of your variable:

```
def function(data)
    dataf = data.copy()
```

I would also suggest to use `numpy.multiply` instead of `*=`:

```
data = numpy.multiply(data, mask)
```